# Validad login con Api REST y ANGULAR

Tags: angular, api, spring-boot, rest

llevo ya unas horas con este problema, no me valida el usuario si realmente existe o no en la base de datos, mi api rest funciona  a la perfección y valida, con el json, pero al tratar de integrarlo con el angular, no me funciona como debe (No me muestra error en consola, ni en codigo) y no he logrado llegar a una solución, agradecería que me pudieran ayudar... 
ESTE SERIA MI LOGIN.component.html

```
<div class="contenedor"> 
<h1>Iniciar Sesion</h1><br>
<p>¡Bienvenido!</p>
<p>Por favor ingresar sus datos correctamente</p><br><br>

<p>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>CORREO ELECTRONICO </mat-label>
        <input matInput #correo>
    </mat-form-field><br>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>CONTRASEÑA </mat-label>
        <input matInput type="password" #contrasena>
    </mat-form-field><br>

</p>
<button class="boton_personalizado" (click)="loginUsuario(correo.value, contrasena.value)">Iniciar 
Sesion</button>

<ul><a class="registro" [routerLink]="['/registro']">¿No estas registrado? Registrate aqui!</a></ul>

<ul><a class="recuperar" [routerLink]="['/recuperarc']">¿Olvido su contraseña?</a></ul>
</div>
```

ESTE ES MI Login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsuariosService } from 'src/app/services/usuarios-service.service'
import { Usuarios } from 'src/models/Usuarios';
import { Location, NgIf } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.css',]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private usuariosService: UsuariosService,
private ubicacion: Location) { }

ngOnInit(): void {

}

loginUsuario(correo: string,contraseña: string): boolean{
if(!correo){
  alert("Campo correo vacio");
  return;
}
if(!contraseña){
  alert("Campo contraseña");
  return;
}
if(this.loginUsuario != null){
  alert("Acceso denegado")
}else {
  alert("Acceso permitido")
}
this.usuariosService.loginUsuario({correo, contraseña} as Usuarios)
  .subscribe(_=> this.volver());
}

volver(): void{
this.ubicacion.back();
}
}
```

ESTE ES MI USUARIO.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Usuarios } from 'src/models/Usuarios';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsuariosService {
private URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api'

httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

registrarUsuario(usuarios: Usuarios) {
const suffix = '/registrarUsuario'
return this.http.post<Usuarios>(this.URL+suffix, usuarios, this.httpOptions);
}

loginUsuario(usuarios: Usuarios): Observable<Usuarios> {
const suffix = '/loginUsuario/'
return this.http.post<Usuarios>(this.URL+suffix+usuarios, this.httpOptions);
}


}
```

Y mi models Usuarios

```
export interface Usuarios {
rut: number;
nombre: string;
apellido: string;
telefono: number;
correo: string;
direccion: string; 
contraseña: string;
producto: string;
permiso: string;
```

}

Si necesitan mas parte del código, avísenme por favor, gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

Comment: *no me funciona como debe*... ¿Hay un error, te sale algo en la consola del navegador? Por favor, aclara este detalle

Comment: No, no tengo ningun error, no funciona como debe, no valida con la base de datos, lo modificare

Comment: Revise y no me sale nada en consola, creo que lo que envió  del front, no esta llegando o no esta comparando con lo que tengo en base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te adjunto tres cosas espero que te sean de utilidad:

1.- Veo que esto como conformar la url en el login y en el registro del usuario lo montas de distinta forma aunque estes pasando el mismo objeto en el registro lo pasas como parametro y en el login lo concatenas 
[image: Concatenación vs parametrización]

2.- Veo otro tema auque no creo que para este caso afecte la ruta de registro es '/registrarUsuario' mientras que la de login es '/loginUsuario/' acabando con "/" por lo que si lo concatenas puede darte algun error.

3.- Aunque no conozco mucho angular te dejo un ejemplo en el que añaden unos try/catch para capturar los errores

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'; // don't forget this, or you'll get a runtime error
this.httpClient
      .get("data-url")
      .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        // simple logging, but you can do a lot more, see below
        console.error('An error occurred:', err.error);
      });

// or
this.httpClient
      .get("data-url")
      .subscribe(
        data => console.log('success', data),
        error => console.log('oops', error)
      );
```

o este ejemplo tambien puede ser de utilidad

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry'; // don't forget the imports

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    baseUrl = 'http://localhost';
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    // notice the <T>, making the method generic
    get<T>(url, params): Observable<T> {
      return this.httpClient
          .get<T>(this.baseUrl + url, {params})
          .retry(3) // optionally add the retry
          .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

            if (err.error instanceof Error) {
              // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
              console.error('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
            } else {
              // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
              // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
              console.error(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
            }

            // ...optionally return a default fallback value so app can continue (pick one)
            // which could be a default value
            // return Observable.of<any>({my: "default value..."});
            // or simply an empty observable
            return Observable.empty<T>();
          });
     }
}
```

Esta ultima informacion la he encontrado en [catching-errors-in-angular-httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46019852/12684857)

Comment: Gracias, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema :c